# How to use lapply with get.confusion_matrix() in R?

Tags: r, list, lapply, confusion-matrix, pls

I am performing a PLS-DA analysis in R using the mixOmics package. I have one binary Y variable (presence or absence of wetland) and 21 continuous predictor variables (X) with values ranging from 1 to 100.
I have made the model with the `data_training` dataset and want to predict new outcomes with the `data_validation` dataset. These datasets have exactly the same structure.

My code looks like:

```
library(mixOmics)
model.plsda<-plsda(X,Y, ncomp = 10)
myPredictions <- predict(model.plsda, newdata = data_validation[,-1], dist = "max.dist")
```

I want to predict the outcome based on 10, 9, 8, ... to 2 principal components. By using the `get.confusion_matrix` function, I want to estimate the error rate for every number of principal components.

```
prediction <- myPredictions$class$max.dist[,10] #prediction based on 10 components
confusion.mat = get.confusion_matrix(truth = data_validatie[,1], predicted = prediction)
get.BER(confusion.mat)
```

I can do this seperately for 10 times, but I want do that a little faster. Therefore I was thinking of making a list with the results of `prediction` for every number of components...

```
library(BBmisc)
prediction_test <- myPredictions$class$max.dist
predictions_components <- convertColsToList(prediction_test, name.list = T, name.vector = T, factors.as.char = T)
```

...and then using lapply with the `get.confusion_matrix` and `get.BER` function. But then I don't know how to do that. I have searched on the internet, but I can't find a solution that works. How can I do this?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without reproducible there is no way to test this but you need to convert the code you want to run each time into a function. Something like this:

```
confmat <- function(x) {
        prediction <- myPredictions$class$max.dist[,x] #prediction based on 10 components
        confusion.mat = get.confusion_matrix(truth = data_validatie[,1], predicted = prediction)
        get.BER(confusion.mat)  
}
```

Now lapply:

```
results <- lapply(10:2, confmat)
```

That will return a list with the `get.BER` results for each number of PCs so results[[1]] will be the results for 10 PCs. You will not get values for `prediction` or `confusionmat` unless they are included in the results returned by `get.BER`. If you want all of that, you need to replace the last line to the function with `return(list(prediction, confusionmat, get.BER(confusion.mat))`. This will produce a list of the lists so that `results[[1]][[1]]` will be the results of `prediction` for 10 PCs and `results[[1]][[2]]` and `results[[1]][[3]]` will be `confusionmat` and `get.BER(confusion.mat)` respectively.